# Convert ul li list to string path

Tags: php

Well i have category list like this

```html
<ul>
    <li>level 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>level 2</li>
            <li>level 2</li>
            <li>level 2</li>
            <li>level 2
                <ul>
                    <li>level 3</li>
                    <li>level 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to conver it to this a tried it with php

```html
level 1 => level 2
level 1 => level 2
level 1 => level 2
level 1 => level 2 => level 3 
level 1 => level 2 => level 3
```

Pls help anybody

Comment: I suggest you place any code you have tried to accomplish this along with your question. This will help to ensure you do not get any negative reputation hits. It also allows others to use your code to try and assist you with a working answer.

Comment: You want to convert it in what way? Do want to save it to an array or display it in the manner you have showed in your snippit?

Comment: Also you have closing a tags but no open a tags! This HTML is not valid.

Comment: to display as i show

Comment: With that corrupt html you won't be able to get the expected results.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** This does not exactly match your expected result. But as your HTML is corrupt and it is not clear how exactly it should look like, I repaired it as an assumption.  This answer is intented to point you the direction of traversing.

- I have corrected the html.
- Iterate over LI
- Inside trace back the UL to the firstChilds LI
- Reverse the order

```php
$html = <<<_EOT
<ul>
    <li>level 1</li>
        <ul>
            <li>level 2</li>
            <li>level 2</li>
            <li>level 2</li>
            <li>level 2</li>
            <ul>
                <li>level 3</li>
                <li>level 3</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
</ul>
_EOT;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

/** @var DOMElement $li */
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('li') as $li) {
    $row = [];
    while($li->parentNode) {
        if($li->tagName === 'ul') {
            $row[] = $li->firstChild->nextSibling->nodeValue;
        }
        $li = $li->parentNode;
    }
    echo join(' => ', array_reverse($row, true)), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Which gives the result of

```
level 1
level 1 => level 2
level 1 => level 2
level 1 => level 2
level 1 => level 2
level 1 => level 2 => level 3
level 1 => level 2 => level 3
```